# Why is Java Stream generator unordered?

Tags: java, java-stream

I try to parallelize some work with Java Streams. Let's consider this simple example:

```
Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer get() {
            return generateNewInteger();
        }
    })
    .parallel()
    .forEachOrdered(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that it does not call the `accept` method for `forEachOrdered`, it only works if I use `forEach`. I guess that the problem is that `Stream.generate` internally creates `InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator` that does not have `ORDERED` characteristic.

The question is why? It seems like we know in which order the data is generated. The second question is how to do `forEachOrdered` on parallelized stream with generation of the stream elements?

Comment: It’s unordered, because the specification says so. The reason it doesn’t complete, is that it is *infinite*, combined with implementation details.

Comment: That can be written far more tersely with lambdas.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can just do `.forEachOrdered(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest answer is, `Stream.generate` is unordered, because [it’s specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) says so.

It’s not like if the implementation was trying to process items in order when possible, it’s actually the opposite. Once an operation has been defined to be unordered, the implementation will try to draw a benefit from the unordered nature, whenever possible. If you experience something that looks like a source order in an unordered operation, there might not have been a way to get a benefit from the unordered processing or the implementation does not use all opportunities yet. Since this might change in a future version or alternative implementation, you must not rely on the order, if the operation has been specified to be unordered.

The intention behind defining `Stream.generate` as unordered might become clearer when comparing with `Stream.iterate`, which is ordered. The function passed to `iterate` will receive its previous element, so there is a previous-subsequent relationship between the elements, hence, an ordering. The supplier passed `Stream.generate` doesn’t receive a previous element, in other words, has no relationship to a previous element when considering the functional signature only. That works for `Stream.generate(() -> constant)` or `Stream.generate(Type::new)` like use cases, but less for `Stream.generate(instance::statefulOp)`, which seems not to be the intended primary use case. It still works, if the operation is thread safe and you can live with the unordered nature of the stream.

The reason why your example does never make progress is that the implementation of `forEachOrdered` actually does not consider the unordered nature, but tries to process the chunks after splitting in the encounter order, i.e. all sub-tasks try buffering their elements, so that they can pass them to the action, once the sub-tasks to their left have been completed. Of course, buffering and infinite sources don’t play well together, especially, since the underlying `InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator` will split into sub-tasks that are infinite on their own. In principle, there is a leftmost task that could feed its elements directly to the action, but that tasks seems to be somewhere in the queue, waiting to become activated, which will never happen as all worker threads are already busy processing the other infinite sub-tasks. Eventually, the entire operation will break with an `OutOfMemoryError`, if you let it run long enough…